Statically building Jasper in a Dockerfile in order to build Graphicsmagick
I have a Dockerfile with a bunch of sources as I am trying to statically build GraphicsMagick. Firstly though I need to deal with all the dependencies, of which Jasper (and others) are required. Here is the Dockerfile;
# Stage 1: Get all dependencies
FROM ubuntu:latest AS builder

# Set environment variables
ENV SOURCES=/tmp/gm_sources
ENV PREFIX=/tmp/gm_build
ENV PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig"

# Install updates and dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    binutils \
    build-essential \
    autoconf \
    automake \
    ca-certificates \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    make \
    pkg-config \
    libtool \
    cmake \
    nasm \
    ninja-build \
    wget \
    gettext \
    imagemagick \
    xmlto 

# Create the SOURCES directory
RUN mkdir -p "${SOURCES}" "${PREFIX}"

# Build bzip2
ADD bzip2-latest.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/bzip2-1.0.8"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" make clean && \
    make CFLAGS="-static -O2 -Wall -fPIC -Wformat -Werror=format-security" libbz2.a && \
    make install PREFIX="${PREFIX}"

# Build giflib
ADD giflib-5.2.2.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/giflib-5.2.2"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" make clean && \
    make CFLAGS="-static -O2 -Wall -fPIC -Wformat -Werror=format-security" libgif.a && \
    make install PREFIX="${PREFIX}"

# Build libjpeg
ADD jpegsrc.v9f.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/jpeg-9f"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" \
    ./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-shared && \
    make && make install

# Build zlib
ADD zlib-1.3.1.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/zlib-1.3.1"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -Wno-dev -G"Ninja" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${PREFIX}" \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fPIC" \
    .. && \
    ninja && ninja install

# Build libpng (after zlib)
ADD libpng-1.6.44.tar.xz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/libpng-1.6.44"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -Wno-dev -G"Ninja" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${PREFIX}" \
    -DZLIB_LIBRARY="${PREFIX}/lib/libz.a" -DZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR="${PREFIX}/include" \
    .. && \
    ninja && ninja install

# Build jpegoptim
ADD v1.5.5.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/jpegoptim-1.5.5"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" LDFLAGS="-static" \
    ./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" \
    --with-arith \
    --with-libjpeg="${PREFIX}" && \
    make && make install

# Build libyuv
RUN mkdir -p "${SOURCES}/libyuv-stable"
ADD stable.tar.gz "${SOURCES}/libyuv-stable"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/libyuv-stable"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -Wno-dev -G"Ninja" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${PREFIX}" \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fPIC" \
    .. && \
    ninja && ninja install

# Build libwebp (after libyuv)
ADD libwebp-1.4.0.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/libwebp-1.4.0"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" ./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-libwebpmux \
    --enable-libwebpdemux \
    --with-libyuv-include-dir="${PREFIX}/include" \
    --with-libyuv-lib-dir="${PREFIX}/lib" && \
    make && make install

# Build libde265
ADD libde265-1.0.15.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/libde265-1.0.15"
RUN CFLAGS="-fPIC" CXXFLAGS="-fPIC" \
    ./autogen.sh && \
    ./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-dec265 \
    --disable-sherlock265 \
    && make && make install

# Build libheif (after libde265)
ADD libheif-1.19.1.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/libheif-1.19.1"
RUN mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -G"Ninja" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${PREFIX}" \
    -DWITH_LIBDE265=ON -DLIBDE265_INCLUDE_DIR="${PREFIX}/include" \
    -DLIBDE265_LIBRARY="${PREFIX}/lib/libde265.a" \
    -DWITH_LIBSHARPYUV=ON \
    -DWITH_EXAMPLES=OFF -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fPIC" \
    .. && \
    ninja && ninja install

# Build zstd
ADD zstd-1.5.6.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/zstd-1.5.6/build/cmake"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -Wno-dev -G"Ninja" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${PREFIX}" \
    .. && \
    ninja && ninja install

# Build xz
ADD xz-5.6.3.tar.xz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/xz-5.6.3"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -Wno-dev -G"Ninja" \
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${PREFIX}" \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-static" -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-static" \
    .. && \
    ninja && ninja install

# Build libtiff
ADD libtiff-v4.7.0.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/libtiff-v4.7.0"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" autoreconf -fiv && \
    ./autogen.sh && \
    autoupdate && \
    ./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" \
    --disable-shared \
    --with-zlib-include-dir="${PREFIX}/include" \
    --with-zlib-lib-dir="${PREFIX}/lib" \
    --with-jpeg-include-dir="${PREFIX}/include" \
    --with-jpeg-lib-dir="${PREFIX}/lib" \
    --with-webp-include-dir="${PREFIX}/include" \
    --with-lzma-include-dir="${PREFIX}/include" \
    --with-lzma-lib-dir="${PREFIX}/lib" \
    --with-zstd-include-dir="${PREFIX}/include" \
    --with-zstd-lib-dir="${PREFIX}/lib" && \
    make && make install

# Build JasPer statically
ADD jasper-4.2.4.tar.gz "${SOURCES}" 
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/jasper-4.2.4/"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" \
    mkdir build2 && cd build2 && \
    cmake -G"Ninja" \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${PREFIX}" \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_SHARED=OFF \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_MULTITHREADING_SUPPORT=ON \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_DOC=OFF \
        -DJAS_INCLUDE_HEIC_CODEC=ON \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_HEIC_CODEC=ON \
        -DJAS_INCLUDE_JPG_CODEC=ON \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_JPG_CODEC=ON \
        -DALLOW_IN_SOURCE_BUILD=ON \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_CXX=ON \
        -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fPIC" \
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fPIC" \
        -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-L${PREFIX}/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lde265 -lheif -lstdc++" \
    .. && ninja && ninja install

# Build lcms2 statically
ADD lcms2-2.16.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/lcms2-2.16"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" ./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-shared && \
    ninja && ninja install

# Build Ghostscript (static)
ADD ghostscript-10.04.0.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/ghostscript-10.04.0"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" ./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --without-x && \
    ninja && ninja install

# Build gperftools
ADD gperftools-2.16.tar.gz "${SOURCES}"
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/gperftools-gperftools-2.16"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" autoupdate && \
    autoreconf -fiv && \
    CPPFLAGS="-I${PREFIX}/include" \
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PREFIX}/lib/pkgconfig" \
    ./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --enable-cpu-profiler \
    --enable-heap-profiler \
    --disable-heap-checker \
    --disable-debugalloc \
    --enable-libunwind \
    --with-pic && \
    ninja && \
    ninja install

I cannot get jasper to build and I think it's to do with c++ linking (but I am not sure).
As a check I added these to my Jasper stage;
pkg-config --libs --static --cflags libde265 libheif && \
gcc -print-libgcc-file-name && \
ls -l ${PREFIX}/lib/libde265.a ${PREFIX}/lib/libheif.a && \...

Here it shows that it can find the libs;
0.128 -I/tmp/gm_build/include -I/tmp/gm_build/include/webp -lde265 -L/tmp/gm_build/lib @LIBS_PRIVATE@ -lheif -lstdc++ -lde265 -L/tmp/gm_build/lib @LIBS_PRIVATE@ -lsharpyuv -lm 
0.129 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/libgcc.a
0.130 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 13163200 Nov  8 13:11 /tmp/gm_build/lib/libde265.a
0.130 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4039384 Nov  8 13:13 /tmp/gm_build/lib/libheif.a

Here is the error when I run docker build -t gm-test .
=> ERROR [46/55] RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/tmp/gm_build/lib/pkgconfig"     mkdir build2 && cd build2 &&     cmake -G"Ninja"         -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release       0.3s
------
 > [46/55] RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/tmp/gm_build/lib/pkgconfig"     mkdir build2 && cd build2 &&     cmake -G"Ninja"         -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release         -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/tmp/gm_build"         -DJAS_ENABLE_SHARED=OFF         -DJAS_ENABLE_MULTITHREADING_SUPPORT=ON         -DJAS_ENABLE_DOC=OFF         -DJAS_INCLUDE_HEIC_CODEC=ON         -DJAS_ENABLE_HEIC_CODEC=ON         -DJAS_INCLUDE_JPG_CODEC=ON         -DJAS_ENABLE_JPG_CODEC=ON         -DALLOW_IN_SOURCE_BUILD=ON         -DJAS_ENABLE_CXX=ON         -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fPIC"         -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fPIC"        -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-L/tmp/gm_build/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lde265 -lheif -lstdc++"     .. && ninja && ninja install:
0.128 Software version: 4.2.4
0.128 Shared library ABI version: 7
0.128 Shared library build version: 7.0.0
0.128 CMAKE_VERSION: 3.28.3
0.171 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.2.0
0.185 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
0.243 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
0.243 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
0.305 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - broken
0.305 CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
0.305   The C compiler
0.305 
0.305     "/usr/bin/cc"
0.305 
0.305   is not able to compile a simple test program.
0.305 
0.305   It fails with the following output:
0.305 
0.305     Change Dir: '/tmp/gm_sources/jasper-4.2.4/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-a8DFJD'
0.305     
0.305     Run Build Command(s): /usr/bin/ninja -v cmTC_6ad35
0.305     [1/2] /usr/bin/cc   -fPIC -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_6ad35.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -c /tmp/gm_sources/jasper-4.2.4/build2/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-a8DFJD/testCCompiler.c
0.305     [2/2] : && /usr/bin/cc -fPIC -L/tmp/gm_build/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lde265 -lheif -lstdc++ CMakeFiles/cmTC_6ad35.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_6ad35   && :
0.305     FAILED: cmTC_6ad35 
0.305     : && /usr/bin/cc -fPIC -L/tmp/gm_build/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lde265 -lheif -lstdc++ CMakeFiles/cmTC_6ad35.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o cmTC_6ad35   && :
0.305     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s: No such file or directory
0.305     /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s: No such file or directory
0.305     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
0.305     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
0.305     
0.305     
0.305 
0.305   
0.305 
0.305   CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
0.305 Call Stack (most recent call first):
0.305   CMakeLists.txt:54 (project)
0.305 
0.305 
0.306 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
------
Dockerfile:179
--------------------
 178 |     WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/jasper-4.2.4/"
 179 | >>> RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" \
 180 | >>>     mkdir build2 && cd build2 && \
 181 | >>>     cmake -G"Ninja" \
 182 | >>>         -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
 183 | >>>         -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${PREFIX}" \
 184 | >>>         -DJAS_ENABLE_SHARED=OFF \
 185 | >>>         -DJAS_ENABLE_MULTITHREADING_SUPPORT=ON \
 186 | >>>         -DJAS_ENABLE_DOC=OFF \
 187 | >>>         -DJAS_INCLUDE_HEIC_CODEC=ON \
 188 | >>>         -DJAS_ENABLE_HEIC_CODEC=ON \
 189 | >>>         -DJAS_INCLUDE_JPG_CODEC=ON \
 190 | >>>         -DJAS_ENABLE_JPG_CODEC=ON \
 191 | >>>         -DALLOW_IN_SOURCE_BUILD=ON \
 192 | >>>         -DJAS_ENABLE_CXX=ON \
 193 | >>>         -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fPIC" \
 194 | >>>         -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fPIC" \
 195 | >>>      -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-L${PREFIX}/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lde265 -lheif -lstdc++" \
 196 | >>>     .. && ninja && ninja install
 197 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c PKG_CONFIG_PATH=\"${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}\"     mkdir build2 && cd build2 &&     cmake -G\"Ninja\"         -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release         -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=\"${PREFIX}\"         -DJAS_ENABLE_SHARED=OFF         -DJAS_ENABLE_MULTITHREADING_SUPPORT=ON         -DJAS_ENABLE_DOC=OFF         -DJAS_INCLUDE_HEIC_CODEC=ON         -DJAS_ENABLE_HEIC_CODEC=ON         -DJAS_INCLUDE_JPG_CODEC=ON         -DJAS_ENABLE_JPG_CODEC=ON         -DALLOW_IN_SOURCE_BUILD=ON         -DJAS_ENABLE_CXX=ON         -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=\"-fPIC\"         -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=\"-fPIC\" \t\t-DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=\"-L${PREFIX}/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lde265 -lheif -lstdc++\"     .. && ninja && ninja install" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1


So I had to explicitly turn off HEIC;
# Build JasPer statically
ADD jasper-4.2.4.tar.gz "${SOURCES}" 
WORKDIR "${SOURCES}/jasper-4.2.4/"
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}" \
    mkdir build2 && cd build2 && \
    cmake -G"Ninja" \
        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="${PREFIX}" \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_SHARED=OFF \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_MULTITHREADING_SUPPORT=ON \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_DOC=OFF \
        -DJAS_INCLUDE_HEIC_CODEC=OFF \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_HEIC_CODEC=OFF \
        -DJAS_INCLUDE_JPG_CODEC=ON \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_JPG_CODEC=ON \
        -DALLOW_IN_SOURCE_BUILD=ON \
        -DJAS_ENABLE_CXX=ON \
        -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fPIC" \
        -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fPIC" \
    .. && ninja && ninja install

Then it builds :-)
